# PayPal integration error with Codigniter 3.1.9

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

My problem is my PayPal works on local server created on xampp with Codiginiter 3.1.9, and php 7,  when i upload this to live sever it shows error.

I am attaching my error screenshot here kindly help me get rid of this or give me some advice i will appreciate your effort.
MY sever details are as follows
PHP 7 and Linux

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure the library was actually uploaded? Because this error means, quite simply, the file doesn't exist..

Comment: thanks for your response file is existed and I have also checked the path that is right

Comment: How are you including the Paypal library in your controller?

Comment: thanks all i have solve the issue by changing the paypal sdk path name to lower case
Linux is case sensitive my bad..!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept this so that others can easily see that the matter is resolved.

Comment: yes i had done this thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Linux is case sensitive make sure your path contains same letters (Lower or Upper case) 
the path I am trying to load have different letters,
review the path with folder and files name carefully according to your library,
in this case paypal library have capital letter but in it's controller there is small name PayPal-PHP-SDK => paypal-php-sdk so becareful while using **linux** server.